# How to check if route matches a pattern with React-Router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

How can I check if a route pattern matches the current route using React Router v4 without the `Route` or `NavLink` components or writing my own regex to match against the route?

For example, if the route is `/users/5/friends/3/pets/10/edit`, I want to be able to check if the route matches a pattern (like the one used by `Route` and `NavLink`). Something like this:

```js
const isEditFriendPetRoute = routeMatches('/users/:userId/friends/:friendId/pets/:petId/edit');

console.log(
  isEditFriendPetRoute 
    ? `Is editing friend's pet`
    : `Is not editing friends pet`
)
```

Comment: Route match object and properties params to match the URL: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router-dom'

const match = matchPath('/users/123', {
  path: '/users/:id',
  exact: true,
  strict: false
})
```

If the URL is matched with the path pattern then it will return an object, else it will return null.

Check the api from the following page
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath